# How to install a python package from repository with several packages?

Tags: python, git, pipenv, pipenv-install

Hello I have a repository with a folder called Packages and inside this several python packages with their setup and all needed configuration in order to installe it.

I can install it localy indicating the complete path to the package, but when I try to do the same from the repository I cannot.

How could I install one of that packages witht pipenv?

I tried the following:

```
pipenv install -e git+https://TOKEN@github.com/user/repo#egg=package

pipenv install -e git+https://TOKEN@github.com/user/repo/branch/path#egg=package
```

But dosen't work I got this error:

> ```
> Error text: Obtaining socks-utils from git+https://****@github.com/............#egg=socks-utils
> ... has inconsistent name: filename has 'package', but metadata has 'UNKNOWN'
> ```

The token is correct I can clone it with that url in another folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [the pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#vcs-support):

> If your repository layout is:
>
> ```
> pkg_dir
> ├── setup.py  # setup.py for package "pkg"
> └── some_module.py
> other_dir
> └── some_file
> some_other_file
> ```
>
> Then, to install from this repository, the syntax would be:
>
> ```
> python -m pip install -e "vcs+protocol://repo_url/#egg=pkg&subdirectory=pkg_dir"
> ```

Hence, you want:

```
pipenv install -e "git+https://TOKEN@github.com/user/repo#egg=package&subdirectory=path"
```

Comment: I get the following error: fatal: unable to access 'https://@github.com/user/repo/': Could not resolve host: @github.com